Using DeleteDuplicates with choosing which item of the pair should be deleted
How to delete duplicates on criteria that an interval is duplicate if it is fully contained in another interval and the smaller interval should be removed.
None of the following works on both lists int1 and int2.
It is dependent on the order of the lists. So DeleteDuplicates may identify that Interval[{15, 18}] is duplicate of Interval[{10, 20}] or Interval[{10, 20}] is duplicate of Interval[{15, 18}], but I want to always delete the smaller interval Interval[{15, 18}].
Correct output is {Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}.
int1 = {Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]};
int2 = RotateLeft[int1];

DeleteDuplicates[int1, 
 IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] || IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &]
DeleteDuplicates[int2, 
 IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] || IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &]

DeleteDuplicates[int1, IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] &]
DeleteDuplicates[int2, IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] &]

DeleteDuplicates[int1, IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &]
DeleteDuplicates[int2, IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &]


{Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

{Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}], Interval[{15, 18}]}

{Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

The method should work also for List with ContainsAll and Region with RegionWithin or similar function where there is possible to say one item is "subset" of another.
Update:
This works for both int1 and int2 but uses sorting which contradicts the advantage of DeleteDuplicates that does not need any sorting.
DeleteDuplicates[ReverseSortBy[#, Abs[Subtract @@ (Identity @@ #)] &],
    IntervalMemberQ] &@int1


{Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{1, 2}]}


For this specific problem, maybe you can use this answer with IntervalMemberQ instead of Divisible. It probably also "contradicts the advantage of DeleteDuplicates" though.

It's a forest with edges meaning that the parent fully contains the child, and @azerbajdzan wants to delete all descendants, remaining all roots.

It's not a forest exactly. It's a directed acyclic graph.

But we can still imagine it as a tree-like graph.

Using RelationGraph :
deleteIntervals[intervals_] :=
 With[{g = RelationGraph[IntervalMemberQ, intervals, DirectedEdges -> True]}, 
  Pick[VertexList[g], VertexInDegree[g],  1]]

int1 = {Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]};
int2 = RotateLeft[int1];
ints = {Interval[{9, 10}], Interval[{7, 11}], Interval[{8, 12}]} (*lericr's list*)


deleteIntervals /@ {int1, int2, ints} // Column


{
 {{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}},
 {{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}},
 {{Interval[{7, 11}], Interval[{8, 12}]}}
}



Adapting this answer by @CarlWoll:
Interval /@ (Internal`ListMin[(First /@ int1) . 
     DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}]] . DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}])
Interval /@ (Internal`ListMin[(First /@ int2) . 
     DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}]] . DiagonalMatrix[{1, -1}])
(*
{Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{1, 2}]}
{Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{1, 2}]}
*)


We first delete identical double intervals.
Then, we check if an intervals is contained in an other intervals by:
-To eliminate the interval to be checked, take the complement.
-Check if any interval of the complement contains the interval to be checked.
-If yes, delete this interval
We can pack both operations into one function:
delint[ints0_] := Module[{ints = DeleteDuplicates[ints0]},
  MapIndexed[
   Function[{x1, x2}, 
    If[AnyTrue[Delete[ints, x2], IntervalMemberQ[#, x1] & ], Nothing, 
     x1]], ints]
  ]

To check if this works:
delint[int1]

{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}

delint[int2]

{Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]}


See edit below in response to azerbajdzan
How about this?
ints = {Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], 
   Interval[{1, 2}]};

(mat = Outer[IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &, ints, ints]) // MatrixForm


dups = DeleteCases[Position[mat, True], {p_, p_}]

Delete[ints, Last /@ dups]

rolling it up:
Delete[ints, 
 Last /@ DeleteCases[
   Position[Outer[IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &, ints, ints], True], {p_, 
    p_}]]

---fix after seeing azerbajdzan's comment---
deleteDups[ints_] := 
 Module[{mat = Outer[IntervalMemberQ[#1, #2] &, ints, ints], dups},
  dups = DeleteCases[Position[mat, True], {p_, p_}] ;
  Delete[ints, List/@Union[Last /@ dups]]
  ]

deleteDups[ints]

FixedPoint[deleteDups, ints]

test:
ints = Interval /@ RandomInteger[100 {-1, 1}, {100, 2}]
deleteDups[ints]
NumberLinePlot[deleteDups[ints]]


For lericr's ints = {Interval[{9, 10}], Interval[{7, 11}], Interval[{8, 12}]} it returns {Interval[], Interval[{7, 11}], Interval[{8, 12}]}. Interval[] should not be there.

@azerbajdzan, good catch. I edited the original.

function
deleteDuplicates[list$_, forwardTest_, backTest_] := Block[
    {mark = Unique@"Null", list, count = 1, dump = {}, test},
    list = Append[list$, mark];
    test = Which[
        #2 === mark, ++count; False,
        forwardTest[#1, #2], True,
        backTest[#1, #2], AppendTo[dump, count]; False,
        True, False
    ] &;
    list = DeleteDuplicates[list, test];
    list[[dump]] = Nothing; list[[-1]] = Nothing;
    list
];

test
list1 = {Interval[{15, 18}], Interval[{10, 20}], Interval[{18, 30}], Interval[{1, 2}]};
list2 = RotateLeft[list1];
test1 = IntervalMemberQ;
test2 = IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] &;
deleteDuplicates[list1, test1, test2]
deleteDuplicates[list2, test1, test2]

comment
By using Trace function, I know one thing that DeleteDuplicates is designed for test function satisfying partial order relationship, mainly transitivity, while the condition you offer apparently contradits with it, so with need to restrict it to forwardTest, i.e. IntervalMemberQ, and meanwhile record the former one which needs to be deleted by backTest, i.e. IntervalMemberQ[#2, #1] &.
update
deleteDuplicates[list_, test_]:=
    Reverse@DeleteDuplicates[Reverse@DeleteDuplicates[list, test], test];


There is an ambiguity in your question. Let's say we have
ints = {Interval[{9, 10}], Interval[{7, 11}], Interval[{8, 12}]}

Since ints[[1]] is contained in both ints[[2]] and ints[[3]], then maybe we should expect only one interval after deleting duplicates, but it clearly can't be one of the larger intervals. On the other hand, your desire to drop the smaller interval means that indeed we should expect 2 remaining intervals, but those two are each a duplicate of the same contained interval, and so are they duplicates of each other?
You may need to "roll your own" algorithm.

I do not see an ambiguity. The first interval is duplicate of both second and third one. Second and third intervals are not duplicates of each other and my code it Update correctly outputs {Interval[{8, 12}], Interval[{7, 11}]}.

You don't see an ambiguity because you invented the semantics. All we have to go on is what you told us. You didn't tell us what to do when two intervals contain a third but neither contains the other. That lack of information was an ambiguity. You've now removed the ambiguity with your comment.

Deleting duplicates is a pairwise operation it does not care about what is relation between triples or any n-tuples for n>2. DeleteDuplicates does not allow you to choose which item to delete if it finds a duplicate pair {#1 , #2} it always delete item #2. All I want is to have another criteria that decides whether #1 or #2 should be deleted.

exactly. that’s why you needed to specify your expectation to eliminate the ambiguity.
